# Is updating ancestor components during componentWillReceiveProps explicitly supported?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I know React supports calling `setState` during [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> `componentWillReceiveProps()` is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare `this.props` and `nextProps` and perform state transitions using `this.setState()` in this method.

But the documentation doesn't say anything about actions that trigger updates to **ancestor** components like changing the router location or dispatching redux actions.

That's what I'm doing in one of my views, and it's causing bugs:

```
class MyView extends React.Component<void, Props, void> {
  setMissingQuery = (props: Props = this.props) => {
    const {date, location: {query: {view}}} = props
    if (!view || !Number.isFinite(date.getTime())) {
      const {router} = this.context
      const {location: {pathname, query}} = this.props
      const newQuery = {...query}
      if (!view) newQuery.view = 'month'
      if (!Number.isFinite(date.getTime())) newQuery.date = moment().format(DATE_FORMAT)
      router.replace({
        pathname,
        query: newQuery,
      })
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setMissingQuery()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props) {
    this.setMissingQuery(nextProps)
    if (nextProps.selectedShift && nextProps.selectedShift !== this.props.selectedShift) {
      const {selectedShift, dispatch} = nextProps
      dispatch(setEditingShiftProps(selectedShift))
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

But if it happens to call both `router.replace` and `dispatch(setEditingShiftProps(selectedShift))` in a single call to `componentWillReceiveProps`, my React UI stops responding and I see the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: `findComponentRoot(..., .0.0.2.0.0.$1/=11=2$0.$0.0.0.0.1.1.1.1:$0.0.0.$header_0.0)`: Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a `<tbody>` when using tables, nesting tags like `<form>`, `<p>`, or `<a>`, or using non-SVG elements in an `<svg>` parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.

I have also seen this same error when I mistakenly dispatched actions during a `componentWillUpdate`, but I have switched to using `componentDidUpdate`.  The error happens because I am rendering a `react-big-calendar` component, and somehow the control flow causes React to call its `componentWillReceiveProps` to be called twice before calling its `componentDidUpdate`.

If I wrap the `router.replace` and `dispatch` calls in a `setTimeout`, the error goes away.

Comment: Try putting it in componentDidMount

Comment: @Dibesjr that doesn't fix the bug, and furthermore, I need to be able to respond to prop changes any time after the component mounts, so I have to use `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: @Dibesjr as I mentioned, I solved my problem with `setTimeout`, but I'm trying to determine if React explicitly supports triggering ancestor updates during `componentWillReceiveProps`.